# QGIS Updating three layers at a time by editing the edge where all the three layers concur

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I have a map with three main layers:

- Roads (Polygons)
- Sidewalks (Polygons)
- Curbs (Multilinestrings)

I need to adjust the edge where all the three layers concur to the cartography layer (the gray lines(the lines indicated by the red arrow)) using snapping to cartography layer. Note that the three layers concur in the curbs layers' Multilinestrings.

If I use the node tool, I can do it layer by layer. I have to do it aprox. 10.000 times so If I could move (adjust by snapping) the three layers at once I could saves days of work.

I tried by selecting the three layers and using the node tool but did not work.

I Know that in ArcView there is a tool in Topology -> Change the edge shape (I don't know if that's exactly the name of the tool because I have translated it from spanish (Topología -> Cambiar la forma del borde)).

I would like to know if there is a way to do this in QGIS.

[image]

Comment: You could try using the **Geometry Snapper** plugin which allows you to snap selected (or all features) from one layer to a reference layer. Although you have to choose one layer at a time, it is automated.

Comment: @Joseph It can be useful. Does that plugin come with QGIS default installation? I can't find the module anywhere: Neither in the Plugins repository nor in the QGIS options.

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? Can't remember if it was before but it is a core plugin and should already come installed. It should be mentioned in the `Installed` section of the plugin repository. If it is enabled, it appears in the **Vector** menubar.

Comment: @Joseph I am in v2.12.3. Thanks, It was installed but deactivated. It can be very useful!

Comment: Glad you found it and hopefully it will help ;)